# Change color of a word in beamer

Tags: beamer

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,t,11pt]{beamer}

\definecolor{unime}{rgb}{0.77,0.12,0.23}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=unime}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=unime}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\mybox[2][]{\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=unime!20,inner sep=2pt, anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,#1] {#2};\phantom{#2}}

\setbeamercolor{button}{bg=unime,fg=white}

\newenvironment{stepenumerate}{\begin{enumerate}[<+->]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemize}{\begin{itemize}[<+->]}{\end{itemize} }
\newenvironment{stepenumeratewithalert}{\begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemizewithalert}{\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{itemize} }


\begin{document}

\section{Basic data analysis in STATA}
\subsection{Making graphs}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Basic data analysis in STATA}
\framesubtitle{Making graphs}
\begin{stepitemizewithalert}
\item STATA allows you to draw simple as well as sophisticated graphs. \medskip
\item In most cases, we need very simple graphs in order to establish a correlation between variables.\medskip
\item Before we start we need to assemble our dataset. We want to collect information about US monetary policy, as well as its GDP, consumer price index and stock market price.\medskip
\item We use the dataset AFE1 and it can be download from my website. \medskip
\item The data cover the period 1990 to 2010 and has been downloaded from \mybox[fill=unime]{\href{https://fred.stlouisfed.org/}{\textbf{\textit {FRED}}}} website, which is the FED data archive.\medskip
\end{stepitemizewithalert}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I am using my own color (unime) and I managed to draw a box around the word FRED (which contains a link to a website). However, using my own color, the word FRED cannot be seen when included in the box. How could I change the color of that word only, say in white?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The MWEs you’re posting in your questions (this one as well as others) are by no means minimal. Please show some effort and reduce your code to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, not including _anything_ in between that isn't necessary to reproduce the undesired behavior.

Comment: @doncherry. done

Comment: I wouldn't rely on Don Cherry to provide one with advice on visual matters: have you seen his suit jackets?  ;-)

Comment: @Dario You don't need `\usepackage{hyperref}` with beamer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Use `\textcolor`

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,t,11pt]{beamer}

\definecolor{unime}{rgb}{0.77,0.12,0.23}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=unime}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=unime}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\mybox[2][]{\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=unime!20,inner sep=2pt, anchor=text, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm,#1] {#2};\phantom{#2}}

\setbeamercolor{button}{bg=unime,fg=white}

\newenvironment{stepenumerate}{\begin{enumerate}[<+->]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemize}{\begin{itemize}[<+->]}{\end{itemize} }
\newenvironment{stepenumeratewithalert}{\begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemizewithalert}{\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{itemize} }


\begin{document}

\section{Basic data analysis in STATA}
\subsection{Making graphs}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Basic data analysis in STATA}
\framesubtitle{Making graphs}
\begin{stepitemizewithalert}
\item STATA allows you to draw simple as well as sophisticated graphs. \medskip
\item In most cases, we need very simple graphs in order to establish a correlation between variables.\medskip
\item Before we start we need to assemble our dataset. We want to collect information about US monetary policy, as well as its GDP, consumer price index and stock market price.\medskip
\item We use the dataset AFE1 and it can be download from my website. \medskip
\item The data cover the period 1990 to 2010 and has been downloaded from \mybox[fill=unime]{\href{https://fred.stlouisfed.org/}{\textbf{\textit{\textcolor{white}{FRED}}}}} website, which is the FED data archive.\medskip
\end{stepitemizewithalert}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Much easier than I thought. Thanks a lot for your help.